# Is there a way to get just the pid of a process with its name for the purpose of suspending it for a set time

Tags: python, operating-system, psutil

I need to gain the pid of a program in order to suspend it temporarily. How can I gain the pid of a program using python with just its username in order to use this pid along with psutil to suspend the process? Let's just call it process.exe for now.

1. I have tried using `item for item` along with `psuti`. However, this gives me additional text along with the pid and I am unsure how to remove this unnecesary text.
2. I have tried using `os.getpid` but this gives me the pid of Python rather than the process I want to get the pid of.

1.

```
import psutil
pid = [item for item in psutil.process_iter() if item.name() == 'process.exe']
print(pid)
```

2.

```
import os
pid = os.getpid()
print(pid)
```

For (1) I want the output to just be

```
pid=x
```

However, right now it is:

```
[psutil.Process(pid=x, name='process.exe', started='14:11:40')]
```

Answer (score 0):

In 1,  you are receiving process object which contains all the information about process, you can use the process object to fetch the pid:

```
pid[0].pid
```

In 2nd ,

> os.getpid()

returns the process id of python interpreter and is of hardly any use under python interpreter, only use it when you are running some python script to get its process id.